# Frame doesn't update

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I did this...

```
public class ButtonCustomRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        var frame = Control.Frame;

        var newSize = frame.Height * 0.8;

        Control.ImageView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, newSize, newSize);
    }
}
```

But the image's frame doesn't change. Not in the debugger straight after the assignment, nor on the screen.

What's the mystery?

The XAML is simple...

```
<ContentPage.Content>
   <Button Image="tick_white.png" />
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: are you sure your renderer getting called?

Comment: Yes. And it doesn’t update it when I step through that line. Give it a go!

Comment: Can you share your Button code from the Xamarin Forms page

Comment: @Saamer It's as simple as can be.

Comment: How did you figure it out, so curious

Comment: @Saamer I meant that the XAML was simple. I must have chopped that text out of the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to do this by changing edge insets.

```
Control.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(...);
```

Comment: And you just passed 0 into the UIEdgeInsets constructor?

Comment: @Saamer I passed in a percentage of the height of the button as the top and bottom insets. The left and right are left as they were. I haven't worked out how to position the label and the image so that they're correctly spaced so I've fudged it for now with some about right values.